# Upper and lower bounds for series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does anyone know an upper or/and lower bounds for series
$\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((n+1)^\alpha-n^\alpha)^2 $
where $0<\alpha<1/2$
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Is $\delta$ related to $\alpha$?

Comment: It is $\alpha$, thanks for telling

Answer (score 3):

You could start with
$$
\alpha^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)^{2\alpha - 2} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)^\alpha - n^\alpha)^2 \le \alpha^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2\alpha - 2}.
$$
Both series converge as long as $\alpha < 1/2$.